# Find group of elements in recursive parent-child with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to find a child node in a xml file which is inside a recursive parent-child attribute. Here is an xml sample:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <nodeA>
            <nodeB>
                <nodeA>
                    <nodeB>
                        <nodeA>
                            <nodeB></nodeB>
                            <nodeB></nodeB>
                            <nodeB></nodeB>         
                        </nodeA>
                    </nodeB>
                    <nodeB>
                        <nodeA>
                            <nodeB></nodeB>
                            <nodeB></nodeB>                     
                        </nodeA>            
                    </nodeB>
                    <nodeB>
                        <nodeA>
                            <nodeB></nodeB>                     
                        </nodeA>            
                    </nodeB>                        
                </nodeA>
            </nodeB>
            <nodeB>
                <nodeA>
                    <nodeB>
                        <nodeA>
                            <nodeB></nodeB>                     
                        </nodeA>
                    </nodeB>            
                </nodeA>            
            </nodeB>
        </nodeA>
    </element>
</root>
```

I can find all nodes without a nodeA child with:

> //nodeB[not(nodeA)]

but I need to select the first (and only the first) `nodeB` group without a `nodeA` child, practically the first **three** occurences of `nodeB`in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is

```
(//nodeA)[nodeB[not(nodeA)]][1]/nodeB
```

Your XPath is almost right - you just need to UP on one level (to nodeA group) and choose first one. Note that XPath collection are 1-indexed instead of classic 0-indexed.

**UPD:** And round brackets to correctly control the priority of operators.

Comment: That one doesn't work for me (selects all leaf level nodeBs instead of first three) but this one works (I just modified yours) `(//nodeA)[nodeB[not(nodeA)]][1]/nodeB`

Comment: great, just wrote directly here, added round brackets to correctly prioritize operators.

Answer (score 1):

With the query you've already got you're only a couple steps away from what you want.

Starting with `//nodeB[not(nodeA)]` you want to go up one level to the parents `/..`, but you only want the parent of the first group `(//nodeB[not(nodeA)]/..)[1]` and of course you want the nodeBs without child nodeAs for the final result of:

```
(//nodeB[not(nodeA)]/..)[1]/nodeB[not(nodeA)]
```

Comment: Thank you, It works. Last not(nodeA) is useless. I used this
(//nodeB[not(nodeA)]/..)[1]/nodeB.

Comment: Usesless? What if the structure ended up as `<nodeA><nodeB/><nodeB/><nodeB><nodeA/></nodeB></nodeA>` would you want the third `nodeB` that contains a `nodeA`?  Including the not(nodeA) in the final test guardes against this situation.